# Akka Http: How to handle high throughput through a proxy?

Tags: scala, proxy, akka, akka-http, http-proxy

**I would like to handle 3.000 requests per second via proxy usage.**

The following code **without proxy works without problems** and can handle **3.000 requests per second** with an average send-response time of **~50MS per request**:

```
Http(context.system)
  .singleRequest(request) // live without proxies -> speed boost by over 100%
  .flatMap(_.toStrict(2.seconds)) // locally it might take longer than 2 seconds
  .flatMap { resp =>
    Unmarshal(resp.entity).to[String].map((resp.status, _)) 
  }
```

---

But now I would like to archive the **same but via Proxy usage**:

```
val httpsProxyTransport = ClientTransport.httpsProxy(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("proxyip", 8888))
val settings: ConnectionPoolSettings = ConnectionPoolSettings(context.system)
                  .withTransport(httpsProxyTransport)
                  .withMaxRetries(0)
                  .withMaxConnectionBackoff(2.seconds) 

Http(context.system)
    .singleRequest(request, settings = settings) 
    .flatMap(_.toStrict(2.seconds)) 
    .flatMap { resp =>
      Unmarshal(resp.entity).to[String].map((resp.status, _)) 
    }
```

**Problem** is that the proxy version:

- **1.000** requests / second -> average send-response time of **~50MS** per request **just like the solution without proxy**
- **1.500** requests / second -> average send-response time of **~80MS** per request
- **2.000** requests / second -> average send-response time of **~150MS** per request

The proxy version gets worse in terms of average response time the more I try to send through. I doubt the problems lies on the end of the proxy, as I've also tried to use 3 different proxies at the same time to balance like 1.000 requests per proxy, but it showed the same increase in average response time.

**Any ideas, what could under the hood limit the https proxy requests?**

(It feels kind of as if the proxy version isn't using multiple cores in parallel.)

---

```
host-connection-pool {   
  max-connections = 650
  max-retries = 0
  max-open-requests = 1024  
  idle-timeout = 5 s
}
```

---

```
dispatcher-io {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 350  
    keep-alive-time = 60s
    allow-core-timeout = on
  }
  shutdown-timeout = 60s
  throughput = 1
}
```

---

Comment: Are you sure that the three proxies are actually different proxies or not alternative names for the same proxy?  The test for if it's proxy-side or client-side is to run 2 instances of your application at 1000 requests/sec and see if that matches 1 instance at 2000 requests/sec.

Comment: Good idea with the test, I ran 3 applications with 1.000 requests/sec each, with all 3 applications to the same proxy and it worked without problems. All 3 applications have around ~50MS. So it seems that the problem is on the client-side. I should also mention that the proxies are set up by me on different servers. Any ideas what it could be on the client-side?

Comment: For the non-proxy case, are all the requests to the same host?

Comment: Yes all to the same host